# How do I count how many checkboxes are selected on a page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, css-selectors

I want to count how many checkboxes on my page are selected using jQuery.  I've written the following code:

```
      var numberOfCheckboxesSelected = 0;
      $(':checkbox').each(function(checkbox) {
          if (checkbox.attr('checked'))
              numberOfCheckboxesSelected++;
      });
```

However, my code errors out with the message "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the third line.

How do I count how many checkboxes are selected on my page?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

jQuery supports the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) pseudo-selector.

```
var n = $("input:checked").length;
```

This will work for radio buttons as well as checkboxes.  If you just want checkboxes, but also have radio buttons on the page:

```
var n = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
```

Comment: You should do `input:checkbox` instead of just `:checkbox` so jQuery doesn't look at *all* elements on the page.

Answer (score 5):

Try this(to avoid counting any selected radio buttons):

```
var numberOfCheckboxesSelected = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 3):

The first argument passed to the callback in [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is the index, not the element.  You should use `this` or a second argument:

```
$(':checkbox').each(function(idx, checkbox) {
      if (checkbox.attr('checked'))
          numberOfCheckboxesSelected++;
});
```

Moreover, the easier way to do this is to select only the checked elements with the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector and then check the selection's [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property:

```
var numberOfCheckboxesSelected = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input:checked").length
```

this will return the count of checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myDIV').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
  var $checkbox = $('#myDIV').find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    $count = 0,
    $counter = $('#myDIV').find('.counter');
  $checkbox.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $count++;
    }
  });
  $counter.text($count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDIV">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> label
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> label
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> label
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> label
  </label>
  <br>
  <span class="counter">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).