# Check and Count number of checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii, yii2

I am creating checkboxes(Array of checkbox) as per number of users.
If there is no user than checkbox will not created.

**Problem :** 
I want to check that if checkbox(es) is/are exist or not and
 if checkbox(es) exist than i want to count checkboxes that are checked.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($companyusers) && $companyusers != array()) {
        foreach ($companyusers as $key => $value) {
            ?>
            <div class="div_to_hide">
                <label class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block !important">
                    <input name="noti[<?php echo $value->id; ?>]" id="" type="checkbox" class="checkbox_input" value="<?= $value->first_name ?>">
                      <span class="search_text">
                          <?= $value->first_name ?>
                      </span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn smbtn btn-success">
            <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Send'); ?>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796036/how-do-i-count-how-many-checkboxes-are-selected-on-a-page-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/r00xxgk5/

```
if($('input:checkbox[name="noti[]"]').length > 0) { // check length of checkbox if > 0
   var sList = "";
   $('input:checkbox[name="noti[]"]').each(function () { // loop throgh all checkbox and detect if checked or not
        sList += "(" + $(this).val() + "-" + (this.checked ? "checked" : "not checked") + ")";
   });
   console.log (sList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using count:

```
count($noti);
```